# How to parse potentially invalid javascript fragments with babel/parser, convert to AST?

Tags: javascript, parsing, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to produce ASTs from Javascript fragments using `@babel/parser`:

```
const parse = require('@babel/parser').parse;

const fragment = 'if (x > 3) {';

const ast = parse(fragment, {
  allowImportExportEverywhere: true,
  allowAwaitOutsideFunction: true,
  allowReturnOutsideFunction: true,
  allowSuperOutsideMethod: true,
  sourceType: 'unambiguous',
  plugins: ['jsx'],
});
```

...which productes:

```
{ [SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:12)
] pos: 12, loc: Position { line: 1, column: 12 } }
```

...or a thrown exception.

Is it possible to force the parser to accept these fragments?  Or is there an alternative to babel parse that can handle this?

I realize the resulting AST will also be invalid, but it doesn't matter for my use-case.

Comment: I think by definition you can't parse invalid code. You could tokenize it.

Comment: There is no AST that represents invalid code.

Comment: @BenWest makes sense, if you want to make an answer ill accept it